# Set value in ng-repeat to another value once (only on page-load)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, toggle

I have this code;

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, entry) in entryDetails.Responses" class="responseEntry">
    <h4 ng-click="box=!box"><i ng-class="(!box ? 'fa fa-arrow-down' : 'fa fa-arrow-right')"></i> {{key}}</h4>
    <pre data-slide-toggle="box"><code>{{entry | json}}</code></pre>
</div>
```

How can I set each `box` box variable to another value (`false` in this case) so my toggles are closed on page-load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) will solve this.

`ng-init="box = false"`

it will create a variable `box` in each and every repeat and initialize it to `true`

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, entry) in entryDetails.Responses" class="responseEntry" ng-init="box = false">
    <h4 ng-click="box=!box"><i ng-class="(!box ? 'fa fa-arrow-down' : 'fa fa-arrow-right')"></i> {{key}}</h4>
    <pre data-slide-toggle="box"><code>{{entry | json}}</code></pre>
</div>
```

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat.

Comment: My bad, it should've been init to `false`. I've added an initial `display: none` to the `<pre>` tag combined with your `ng-init` and it works great now, thanks a lot!

Comment: chreez :) glad to help you :)